# Solr Boost Function/Query

Tags: solr, lucene

How can I boost a query by a string(map) field? I've found only resources explaining date boosting.

E.g. these documents should be boosted in this order:

doc1:

"specIds": [
          "6":12,
          "7":3
        ]
doc2:

"specIds": [
          "6":18,
          "14":5
        ]

doc3:

"specIds": [
          "6":1,
          "14":3
        ]

Here specIds has key and value. I want search on the basic of key and boost docs by their values.

Ex: fq=specIds:(6)

Result Order:  (Random)

doc1
doc2
doc3

I want results as:

doc3
doc1
doc2

I am new to solr, Please help how can I get this.

Comment: How many different specId keys are talking about? And you want to inversely boost the term, right? A lower value should result in a larger boost? And do you really want a boost? Not just a sort?

Comment: There can be any number of different specId and I want sorting on the basis of values in specId. I am using keys to find result set.

Comment: What scale are we talking about? 100? 1000? 100000? a million? Usually the easiest solution is to flatten the field name and index them as `specIds_6: <value>` and then `sort=specIds_6`. As long as you have docValues enabled for the field, it should be performant.

Comment: Got it. @MatsLindh Thanks.

Comment: specIds field is not fix in number so how will I create schema?

Comment: You add a dynamic field named `specIds_*` with integer as its type.